# Can I use count(*) and AND in select sql query at same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\6th sem\DNT\tutorials\application\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
sc.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = sc;

//cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM dictionary WHERE word=@Word AND user=@Unique";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Word", textBox_word.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unique", frm.textUserName);
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dictionary WHERE word=@Word AND user=@Unique";

int z = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
MessageBox.Show(z.ToString());

if (z >= 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("word already entered in your id");
}
else
{
}
```

My code is always going in else part and output of above query is always 0 !!!

Comment: What should the correct return value be?

Comment: What RDBMS is this?  NM... [MSSQLLocalDB] `Dictionary` is a reserved word needing to be escaped. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx  wrap dictionary in []

Comment: dictionary is my table name in visual studio local DATABASE

Comment: Does it work if you wrap dictionary in brackets?   `SELECT count(*) FROM [dictionary] WHERE word=@Word AND user=@Unique";`?  Perhaps cmd.executeSacalar() is throwing an error and since z hasn't been initialized it's going to the else.  From above link... "Although it is syntactically possible to use SQL Server reserved keywords as identifiers and object names in Transact-SQL scripts, ***you can do this only by using delimited identifiers***."

Comment: every time it is going in else block as i have printed z's value using MessageBox.Show();it always shows 0.

Comment: if i remove AND user=@Unique this part then output is not always 0 it depends on my dictionary table entry

Comment: To answer your specific question: yes you can use an AND and count(*) in a SQL query at the same time.

Comment: working but output is always samethat is not desirable and if i remove AND then output is desiring

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use Profiler to see what is being passed to your parameters, but I am highly suspicious of this line:

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unique", frm.textUserName);
```

Don't you want to access the `.text` property of the `textUserName` object, the way you did with the `@Word` parameter?

Comment: actually its the value of form1 which i have used in form 3 using form1 property so no need to worry about that line its absolutely fine and passing only text value for sure

Comment: So use profiler to see what SQL is being executed by your application, and then show us what data you have that you would expect to be returned but is not.   There is no error in your code, so either the parameters you are passing, or your data, is simply not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

finally found an answer...
it was problem with SQL database coloumn name user which they are not allowing i dont know the reason why but that was it in my case.
so i changed the coloumn name to user1 and it works correctly...

Answer (score -1):

suggestion 1:-
Please store the values of **textBox_word.Text** and  **frm.textUserName** in another values and then put here.

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Word", value1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unique",value2);

If still any issue then
Suggestion 2:-

Please debug the code and check what exactly values are comming for value1 and value2